# Background colour sitting over the top and cant see <p> text

Tags: html

```
<div id="nav" style="background-color: purple; width: 100px; height: 1060px; float: left;">
        <p> <a href="../info/info.html">Information</a></p>
        <p> <a href="../../index.html">Home</a></p>
    </div>
```

I want to be able to see my links and i don't know why i cant. I usually use CSS but its a assessment and have to use html styling.
Sorry for the super amateur question.

Comment: Works for me... https://jsfiddle.net/xbgfm159/ . Could it be something else that is preventing it from showing, some unknown CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
    a, a:hover, a:visited{
      color:white;
     }
```

or style inline:

```
<a href="../info/info.html" style="color:white;">Information</a>
```

Hope that helps.
Good luck

Comment: Thanks Mate! I knew it would be simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the color of the `<p>` or `<a>` tags.
Nothing about your HTML says your background color is messing with your tags. It's likely that the blue of the `<a>` tag is what's causing your link to appear missing because standard `<a>` turns links blue, clashing with the purple.

`<p>` and `<a>` also support inline HTML styling.

That said, HTML styling isn't much different from CSS styling.

Why would the assessment care?

You can throw it in a `<style>` block and it'd be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Without css, you will find it difficult to apply `:hover` style but it is possible with javascript (inline as your wish). try to use this one:

```html
<div id="nav" style="background-color: purple; width: 100px; height: 1060px; float: left;">
  <p> <a href="../info/info.html" style="color:black; text-decoration:none;" onmouseover="this.style.color='green'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">Information</a>
  </p>
  <p> <a href="../../index.html" style="color:black; text-decoration:none;" onmouseover="this.style.color='green'" onmouseout="this.style.color='black'">Home</a>
  </p>
</div>
```